# Getting User ID of the newly created user in liferay hook struts action process method

Tags: java, liferay, struts, portlet

Am using Liferay 6.2 GA1 platform

How to get the User ID of the newly created user in the Struts portlet action class method processAction , i am overriding the /admin_user/edit_user action ,

**Purpose** : To get the newly created user id in the action class and save it to another table(in another db).

```
 public void processAction(
        StrutsPortletAction originalStrutsPortletAction,
        PortletConfig portletConfig, ActionRequest actionRequest,
        ActionResponse actionResponse)
    throws Exception {
    ThemeDisplay themeDisplay =
        (ThemeDisplay)actionRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);

    Long currentuser = themeDisplay.getUserId();

    if (currentuser != null) {
        log.info("Wrapped /admin_server/edit_user action");

    }

originalStrutsPortletAction.processAction(
        originalStrutsPortletAction, 
        portletConfig, 
        actionRequest,
        actionResponse);

 User selUser = (User) actionRequest.getAttribute("USER");

    log.info("User ID : "+selUser.getUserId());


}
```

but the user id am getting is the user id of the logged in user.

How to get the new user ID ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just calling processAction of originalStrutsPortletAction does not confirm that user will be created.

So you have to check if SessionErrors is empty by `SessionErrors.isEmpty(actionRequest)`.

After checking this condition you can use below code to get userId of newly created user.

```
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay)actionRequest.getAttribute(
            WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserIdByEmailAddress(themeDisplay.getCompanyId(), ParamUtil.getString(
            actionRequest, "emailAddress"))
```